# Issues loading Flex SWF into Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I'm trying to load a Flex SWF into my Flash SWF, but it's not working. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///C|/Program%20Files/Adobe/Adobe%20Fireworks%20CS6/Configuration/Command%20Panels/Texture Panel.swf contains invalid data.

    at _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager/create()
    at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

And this is my Flash SWF's code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.*;
    import adobe.utils.*;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var myLoader:Loader = new Loader(); addChild(myLoader);

            function systemManagerHandler(event:Event):Boolean { event.preventDefault(); return false; }

            myLoader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isBootstrapRoot", systemManagerHandler);
            myLoader.addEventListener("mx.managers.SystemManager.isStageRoot", systemManagerHandler);

            myLoader.load(new URLRequest("Texture Panel.swf"));
        }

    }

}
```

I'd love ANY help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's only part of the stack trace. You seem to have cut off the actual error message.

Comment: IIRC Doesn't a Flex swf have external dependencies (swc files)?

Comment: @spender A Flex SWF only has external dependencies if you compile it using RSLs.  That is the default setting for the Flex Framework--I believe starting with the Flex 4 Framework.  I'm unclear if that is the issue here.  I don't know whether loading a Flex SWF in a SWF will load the signed framework files from Adobe.

Comment: I put the entire stack trace there, but it still doesn't change much... @RIAStar

Comment: @spender I don't have any external dependencies... :/

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Can I disable that?

Comment: @coderkid Yes; there should be a setting in Flash Builder when you add a SWC to the project; it is either RSL or Merged into Code.  You want the latter.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I tried that, and to make sure, I tested this with a blank Flex project SWF - same error.

Comment: I wonder if the error is related to the unescaped space in the file name somehow?  All other spaces appear to be replaced with %20.  I'm just guessing, though--I can't imagine why that would cause errors.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I just tried that and removing the space from the SWF I'm loading, and it did the same thing. Although I really appreciate that effort you guys are putting towards helping me :)

Comment: Just to make sure you got this right: it is the `Texture Panel` Flex app you have to compile with the Flex framework merged in, not the Flash project.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I may be accidentally compiling my Flash project with Flex merged in...I'll check, thanks. @RIAstar

Answer (score 1):

[Tip](http://www.andymoore.ca/2010/11/flash-error-2136-oh-joy/) from andy moore:

1) Flash: File > New > Flash AS3.0 File

2) Copy the entire “library” from your old FLA

3) Paste the entire “library” to the new FLA

4) DELETE THE OLD FILE, IT IS MAGICAL POISON